# Probability of A give B

Tags: probability

> A rare disease affects 1 in 10,000 individuals in the population. 
>   A blood test for the disease is positive for 95% of people with the disease. 
>   However, 0.4% of people without the disease will also test positive.
>   Given that a person (selected at random from the general population) tests positive, what is the probability that she has the disease?

Can someone help me figure this out?

I know the probability of having the disease is 1/10,000.

I know this rule: $\displaystyle P\left(A\mid B\right) = \frac{P\left(A \cap B\right)}{P(B)}$ but in this formula wouldn't $A$ be testing positive which is either $.95$ or $.004$?

Comment: Have you heard of Bayes' rule?

Comment: @snarski ive heard of it, but i seem to see multiple different versions of it and dont know what it does.. Do I need it to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you draw a probability tree?  Once thats' done, Bayes rule is cake.

Comment: To help get your head round the problem, the best thing you could do to start is to write down clearly what are the events $A$ and $B$ of interest in this question.  Then you can start to apply an appropriate formula.

Comment: @ncmathsadist I have a probability tree drawn on my white board. How can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the extended form of Bayes' theorem, since A is a binary virable (a person can either be sick or not sick): $\displaystyle P(A|B) = \frac{(P(B|A)*P(A)}{P(B|A)*P(A)+P(B|A^c)*P(A^c)}$
Note that the question is what the probablity that a person has the disease, given he tested positive. So A would be person having the disease, and B would be testing positive.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(D|+) = {P(D\cap +)\over P(+)},$$
where $+$ means positive test, $D$ means "actually has disease.

Comment: wouldnt it be the other way around?

Comment: Can you use this with the tree?

Comment: But arent we looking for P(D|+)?